# Separating lists in a list through iteration

Tags: python, list

First off, this is a homework assignment, but I've been working on it for a week now and haven't made much headway. My goal for this function is to take a list of lists (each list contains data about a football player) and separate the lists based off of the teams which the players belong to. I also want to add up each player's data so that I wind up with one list for each team with all the player's stats combined.

Here's the code I have so far. The problem I'm currently running into is that some teams are printed multiple times with different data each time. Otherwise it appears to be working correctly. Also, we have the limitation imposed on us that we are not allowed to use classes.

```
def TopRushingTeam2010(team_info_2010): #running into trouble calculating the rusher rating for each team, it also prints out the same team multiple times but with different stats. And just not getting the right numbers and order. 
    total_yards = 0
    total_TD = 0
    total_rush = 0
    total_fum = 0
    #works mostly, but is returning some teams twice, with different stats each time, which
    #should not be happening. so... yeah maybe fix that?
    for item in team_info_2010:
        team = item[0]
        total_yards = item[2]
        total_TD = item[3]
        total_rush = item[1]
        total_fum = item[4]
        new_team_info_2010.append([team, total_yards, total_TD, total_rush, total_fum])

        for other_item in team_info_2010:
            if other_item[0] == team:
                new_team_info_2010.remove([team, total_yards, total_TD, total_rush, total_fum])
                total_yards = total_yards + other_item[2]
                total_TD = total_TD + other_item[3]
                total_rush = total_rush + other_item[1]
                total_fum = total_fum + other_item[4]
                new_team_info_2010.append([team, total_yards, total_TD, total_rush, total_fum])
```

Any help or tips as to which direction I should head, or if I'm even headed in the right direction?

Comment: hint: use a dictionary and iterate through the team_info_2010 once. there's no reason to make this an n-squared algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem is that you are removing from `team_info_2010` while you are iterating through the list. Try deleting that line of code. I don't see a clear reason why you would want to delete from `team_info_2010` and behavior is often undefined when you modify an object while iterating through it. More specifically, try deleting the following line of code:

```
team_info_2010.remove(item)
```

Comment: It is still returning the same team multiple times